# cert in /etc/ssl/cert.pem expired today (MacOS Mojave)

Tags: ssl, ssl-certificate

The cert that is stored in /etc/ssl/cert.pem expired today on my Mojave computer, which has caused problems with my curl commands.  Is there anyway to update it?  I see that my Catalina computer has a newer certificate.  Can I just copy it over to my Mojave computer?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think you have problem with AddTrust CA

> What You Need to Do
>   For most use cases, including certificates serving modern client or server systems, no action is required, whether or not you have issued certificates cross-chained to the AddTrust root.
>
> As of April 30, 2020:  For business processes that depend on very old systems,  Sectigo has made available (by default in the certificate bundles) a new legacy root for cross-signing, the “AAA Certificate Services” root. However, please use extreme caution about any process that depends on very old legacy systems. Systems that have not received the updates necessary to support newer roots such as  Sectigo’s COMODO root will inevitably be missing other essential security updates and should be considered insecure. If you would still like to cross-sign to the AAA Certificate Services root, please contact Sectigo directly.

https://support.sectigo.com/articles/Knowledge/Sectigo-AddTrust-External-CA-Root-Expiring-May-30-2020

Answer (score 12):

Yesterday, the Let's Encrypt *DST Root CA X3* root certificate expired, which is causing similar problems as you experienced: `curl` displays a *SSL certificate problem: certificate has expired* error when trying to access websites using the new Let's Encrypt *ISRG Root X1* certificate.

On macOS Mojave (and maybe others, but this is what I use), the default curl uses certificates in `/etc/ssl/cert.pem` when verifying TLS connections (you can confirm this by by running `curl -v https://example.com 2>&1 | grep CAfile`).

---

The simplest fix is to delete the expired root certificate from the `/etc/ssl/cert.pem` file, assuming its replacement already exists in the file. This is enough to fix the expired *DST Root CA X3*, because its replacement, *ISRG Root X1* already exists in the `/etc/ssl/cert.pem` file. Delete all lines from `### Digital Signature Trust Co.` to `-----END CERTIFICATE-----`.

---

If you need to completely replace `/etc/ssl/cert.pem` with updated certificates, you can replace it with certificates exported from the macOS *System Roots* keychain:

1. Make a backup of the old `/etc/ssl/cert.pem`:

```sh
sudo cp /etc/ssl/cert.pem{,-orig}
```

2. Export system keychain and replace contents of `/etc/ssl/cert.pem`:

```sh
security find-certificate -a -p /System/Library/Keychains/SystemRootCertificates.keychain | sudo tee /etc/ssl/cert.pem >/dev/null
```

Alternatively, you can tell curl to use a different certificate file like this:

```
curl -I --cacert /path/to/certificates.pem https://example.com/
```

Or configure the location of this file using the `CURL_CA_BUNDLE=/path/to/certificates.pem` environment variable.

Comment: I'm on OSX Mojave and it helped me resolve the issue by deleting the expired root certificate from /etc/ssl/cert.pem. Thank you!

Answer (score 5):

For **Mojave** in 2022/02, here is a simple solution:

1. Backup the current version of `/etc/ssl/cert.pem` in your macOS.
2. Download the [new CA certificate](https://curl.se/docs/caextract.html)( **officially recommended** by [curl.se](https://curl.se/)), renaming it to `cert.pem`.
3. Replace the original one with the new one: `sudo mv cert.pem /etc/ssl/cert.pem`.

Answer (score 0):

I tried [Quinn Comendant's solution](https://stackoverflow.com/a/69413675/4119686), but it didn't work.

I ended up solving this by installing OpenSSL and linking the cert.pem file to the one under OpenSSL (in MacOS Mojave):

```sh
$ sudo cp /etc/ssl/cert.pem /etc/ssl/cert.pem.bak

$ brew install openssl

$ brew info openssl
openssl@3: stable 3.0.0 (bottled) [keg-only]
Cryptography and SSL/TLS Toolkit
https://openssl.org/
/usr/local/Cellar/openssl@3/3.0.0 (6,415 files, 28MB)
  Poured from bottle on 2021-10-04 at 11:13:17
From: https://github.com/Homebrew/homebrew-core/blob/HEAD/Formula/openssl@3.rb
License: Apache-2.0
==> Caveats
A CA file has been bootstrapped using certificates from the system
keychain. To add additional certificates, place .pem files in
  /usr/local/etc/openssl@3/certs
...
```

From this we'll know the config is in `/usr/local/etc/openssl@3`, then:

```sh
$ sudo rm /etc/ssl/cert.pem

$ sudo ln -s /usr/local/etc/openssl@3/cert.pem /etc/ssl/cert.pem
```

This solved my problem.

Comment: You can't use Homebrew to fix Let's Encrypt certificates on your machine, because Let's Encrypt certificates don't work and some parts of Homebrew might rely on them.

Answer (score -1):

Thus far, the only working solution I can find is to just upgrade to Catalina. None of the above suggestions work because even Homebrew is broken because most of their mirrors use Let's Encrypt certificates. Adding a new ISRG Root X1 certificate file from http://x1.i.lencr.org/ to the system keychain and exporting to a new /etc/ssl/cert.pem doesn't even fix the problem.

Comment: Not true Michael Lee solution helped. Anyway it's time to create Homebrew replacement that support Mojave without need for upgrading to crap stripped OS versions